# Custom library not recognized inside DSL file in groovyscript part

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, dsl

Context: I'm implementing a Jenkins Pipeline. For this, in order to define the pipeline's parameters I implemented the DSL file.
In the DSL file, I have a parameter of ActiveChoiceParam type, called ORDERS. This parameter will allow me to choose one or more orders numbers at the same time.

Problem: What I want to do is to set the values that gets rendered for ORDERS parameter from a custom library. Basically I have a directory my_libraries with a file, orders.groovy. In this file, there is an order class, with a references list property that contains my values.

The code in the DSL file is as follows:

```
def order = new my_libraries.order()

pipelineJob("111_name_of_pipeline") {
    description("pipeline_description")
    keepDependencies(false)
    parameters {
        stringParam("BRANCH", "master", "The branch")
        activeChoiceParam("ORDERS") {
            description("orders references")
            choiceType('CHECKBOX')
            groovyScript{
                script("return order.references")
                fallbackScript("return ['error']")
}
}
}
}
```

Also, is good to mention that my custom library works well. For example, if I choose to use a ChoiceParam as below, it works, but of course, is not the behaviour I want. I want to select multiple choices.

```
choiceParam("ORDERS", order.references, "Orders references list but single-choice")
```

How can I make order.references available in the script part of groovyScript?

I've tried using global instance of order class, instantiate the class directly in the groovyScript, but no positive result.